# "Route [user.update] not defined" but exists in resource controller, Laravel 4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

UsersController:

```
protected $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($id);
    return View::make('users.edit')->with('current',$current)->with('user',$user);
}

public function update($id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($id);
    ....
    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

Model:

```
protected $table = 'users';
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

Link generated to route (in ../views/users/show):

```
https://.../users/{$id}/edit
```

Form model in edit.blade.php:

```
    {{ Form::model($user, array('route'=>array('user.update',$user->id))) }}
```

Linking to /users/edit throws this exception:

Route [user.update] not defined. (View: .../app/views/users/edit.blade.php)

I don't understand how the route isn't defined when it appears to be clearly defined in the UsersController. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `php artisan routes` in CLI?

Comment: Just a typo change `user.update` to `users.update` for the route in your `Form::model()` declaration.

Comment: @RMcLeod: you're making this too easy! Ha. I was trying to show that you can check routes for future reference :)

Comment: Thank you both -- and now I feel really silly for having missed that. Guess I'm tired... but now that users/edit is loading (and the data binding works!), there is another problem: the CSS for this page is not loading, despite extending the same layouts file as the original users/create page. Does the fact that the userid is inserted between users and edit (users/{$id}/edit) act as if a new directory has been added and therefore requires a new path to the CSS file?

Comment: Yep, just answered my own question -- the generated URL does require a new path backwards.